# Can a CNAME be pointed to a paramterised URL with query params?

Tags: cloud, web-hosting, cname

Can a CNAME for `gameid123.com` be made to point to URLS like:

1. `my_other_website.com/games/gameid123`
2. `my_other_website.com/games?nameid=gameid123`
3. `my_other_website.com/games/gameid123?gameid=gameid123`

So that whenever a user tries to access `gameid123.com`, it instead opens one of these above urls as its home page.

If the above is not possible, then in what ways do I solve this problem?

A request like `gameid123.com/some_api_call/someParam1?blah=blah1` shoul resolve to `my_other_website.com/games/gameid123/some_api_call/someParam1?blah=blah1`

Answer (score 0):

A CNAME can only point at another host (no paths / queries involved). However, there are a number of ways that you can have an incoming request either redirect (or rewrite) the incoming request.

The solution will depend on whether you want the user to end up on `my_other_website` (redirect) or if you want all requests to be via `gameid123.com` (rewrite).

Comment: I want, all request via gameid123.com

Comment: There are a huge number of solutions to rewriting (or forwarding) a request. It will depend on what server / tech you are using, and whether or not you control the `my_other_website` server or not. I would suggest researching this, or posting a new question with these details.